# run C commands in bash script ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, c

The author of this tutorial did a great job but failed to explain his use of `printf` here. It is not working for me. It is found at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays

I use

```
#!/bin/sh


ARRAY=(one two three four [5]=five)

echo "Array size: ${#array[*]}"

echo "Array items:"
for item in ${array[*]}
do
  printf "  %s\n" $item
done

echo "Array index:"
for index in ${!array[*]}
do
  printf "  %d\n" $index
done

echo "Array items and indexes:"
for index in ${!array[*]}
do
  printf "%4d: %s\n" $index ${array[$index]}
done
```

I get

```
cchilders@C02S21TWG8WMMBP:~/fake 
$ ./array_example1.sh 
Array size: 0
Array items:
Array index:
Array items and indexes:
```

how can I run printf and such in a bash script? Thank you

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` makes the script use Korn shell; for `bash` use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @AFH: on Ubuntu, I believe all versions but only have 14.04 to hand, `/bin/sh` is `dash` which is Korn-like but not actually `ksh`; OTOH it sure isn't `bash`. OP: Although C has a standard-library *function* `printf` with the same *name*. the `printf` you use in any shell is not a 'C command'.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: In `bash`, `printf` is a built-in command, but there is also an external program, which should also work, and is probably what is called from `sh`, though the calls should be compatible. But it's your shell that is giving the errors, as `sh` doesn't handle arrays. I apologise: in my first comment I should have said "`#!/bin/sh` makes the script use **Bourne** shell" - your script would probably work with Korn.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - I was simplifying: `/usr/sh` makes the script obey Bourne syntax, but several shells use the same binary and set the syntax rules according to `$0` (`argv[0]`). This is done a lot in Unix/Linux, eg `ls`/`dir`, `cp`/`ln`/`mv`, etc, though not all implementations do this: my Ubuntu doesn't, as `ls -i $(which ...)` shows - indeed, `sh` and `dash` are different, too. You can see why I simplified.